# Python a List of lists Merge

Tags: python

Say I have a list of list like this: (suppose you have no idea how many lists in this list)

```
list=[['food','fish'],['food','meat'],['food','veg'],['sports','football']..]
```

how can I merge the items in the list like the following:

```
list=[['food','fish','meat','veg'],['sports','football','basketball']....]
```

i.e, merge all the nested lists into the same list if they contain one of the same items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `defaultdict` to make a dictionary that maps a type to values and then get the items:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> items = [['food','fish'],['food','meat'],['food','veg'],['sports','football']]
>>> for key, value in items:
...     d[key].append(value)
...     
>>> [[key] + values for key, values in d.items()]
    [['food', 'fish', 'meat', 'veg'], ['sports', 'football']]
```

Comment: Ahh +1 - the relationship seems obvious now you've posted this answer - thanks :) (must need more coffee)

Answer (score 2):

The "compulsory" alternative to `defaultdict` which can work better for data that's already in order of the key and if you don't want to build data structures on it (ie, just work on groups)...

```
data = [['food','fish'],['food','meat'],['food','veg'],['sports','football']]

from itertools import groupby
print [[k] + [i[1] for i in v] for k, v in groupby(data, lambda L: L[0])]
```

But `defaultdict` is more flexible and easier to understand - so go with @Blender's answer.